# Conditional formatting for what my Javascript find in table cell

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, conditional-statements

Im attempting to generate a site to show customer sites status's. I am stuck on some conditional formatting from within jave script.

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","example.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    document.write("<table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>");
    document.write("<th>SITE:</th>");
    document.write("<th>URL:</th>");
    document.write("<th>STATUS:</th>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    { 
    document.write("<tr><td style='font-size:10px'>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("SITE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td style='font-size:10px'>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("URL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td style='font-size:10px'>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("STATUS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
var STAT=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("STATUS");
document.write(STAT)
        if (STAT=="UP")
            {
            document.write('<div style="background-color:#2EFE2E">UP</div>')
            }
        else
            {
            if (STAT=="DOWN")
                {
                document.write('<div style="background-color:#FF0000">DOWN</div>')
                }
            else
                {
                document.write('<div style="background-color:#EDA200">UNKNOWN</div>')
                }
            }
    document.write("</td></tr>");
}
    document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

The problem that I am having is the last section of the script. What I would like is some assitance, in getting the script to look for the word "UP" or "DOWN" in the example XML tag called . Setting different color and text according to the word. Anything else has its own seperate formatting.

For some reason (must be a really silly reason for it), the table cell called STATUS is only showing the last part of the formatting. So instead of looking for the word "UP" or "DOWN" its using the formating for everytrhing else instead. So instead of using this:

```
if (STAT=="UP")
        {
        document.write('<div style="background-color:#2EFE2E">UP</div>')
        }
```

It is using this:

```
else
        {
        document.write('<div style="background-color:#EDA200">UNKNOWN</div>')
        }
```

An example output is here: http://echelonservices.co.uk/test/CUSTOMERS.html

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Please note: JavaScript != Java

Comment: You're doing a synchronous ajax request during page load? *NOOOOoooooo......!*

Comment: This HTML looks like it was taken from 1999. Don't use `document.write` for this sort of thing (it destroys the document in your case) , don't use attributes like `cellpadding` on tables unless you have a very good reason to. Don't write HTML in strings.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
var STAT=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("STATUS");
document.write(STAT)
if (STAT=="UP")
```

...you're comparing an element (the `STATUS` element) with a string. I think you probably meant:

```
var STAT=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("STATUS")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
document.write(STAT)
if (STAT=="UP")
```

...so that you get the value of its first text node. Or you may want `[x]` instead of `[0]`, it's not clear.

Or actually, looking at the surrounding code:

```
var STAT = x[i].getElementsByTagName("STATUS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.write(STAT);
if (STAT=="UP")
```

(But note that you can use `firstChild` rather than `childNodes[0]`.)

---

But can I just strongly suggest **not** using synchronous ajax requests, and not using `document.write`. Instead, put a placeholder in your HTML where you want this table to go:

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

...and then put this at the end of the page:

```
(function() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleReadyStateChange;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "example.xml"); // Async, not sync
    xmlhttp.send();

    function handleReadyStateChange() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 &&
            xmlhttp.status >= 200 &&
            xmlhttp.status < 300) {

            buildTable(xmlhttp.responseXML);
        }
    }

    function buildTable(xmlDoc) {
        var markup, x, i, stat;

        // Build the markup in an array
        markup = ["<table cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' width='100%'></table>"];
        markup.push("<th>SITE:</th>");
        markup.push("<th>URL:</th>");
        markup.push("<th>STATUS:</th>");
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            markup.push("<tr><td style='font-size:10px'>");
            markup.push(x[i].getElementsByTagName("SITE")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
            markup.push("</td><td style='font-size:10px'>");
            markup.push(x[i].getElementsByTagName("URL")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
            markup.push("</td><td style='font-size:10px'>");
            stat = x[i].getElementsByTagName("STATUS")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            markup.push(stat);
            switch (stat) {
                case "UP":
                    markup.push('<div style="background-color:#2EFE2E">UP</div>')
                    break;
                case "DOWN":
                    markup.push('<div style="background-color:#FF0000">DOWN</div>')
                    break;
                default:
                    markup.push('<div style="background-color:#EDA200">UNKNOWN</div>')
                    break;
            }
            markup.push("</td></tr>");
        }
        markup.push("</table>");

        // Put it in the placeholder
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = markup.join("");
    }
})();
```

That's a *minimal* rewrite, note how little actually changed. I basically did these things:

- Making it an *asynchronous* request.
- Building the markup in an array.
- Changed `childNodes[0]` to `firstChild`.
- Putting the table on the page by assigning to `innerHTML` on a placeholder.
- Declaring all variables at the top of the function (as [that's where they are anyway](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)).
- Ensuring all variales *are* in fact declared (you may have had them declared in code you didn't show, but just in case), so we don't fall prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).
- Put everything within a scoping function so we didn't create any globals.

(I had to change the indentation style, I'm afraid I didn't quite "grok" yours.)

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!!
I missed that out completely. This has worked perfectly. I know that the code looks all over the place and all, but it's case of getting it bodged and then cleaning it all up laterz!

Comment: @Echelon: Glad that helped. I've also added to the answer to show how to do this without using a synchronous ajax request (which is poor practice in 2013) and without using `document.write`. I made minimal changes, but hopefully it's useful.